# php - PHPExcel setReadDataOnly(true) is not working with ODS

Tags: phpexcel, ods

Enter *12:00* in an ODS cell and get default Time format, `setReadDataOnly(true)` then `getValue()`, the value is *25569.5*, if format the cell as number then `getValue()`, the value is *0.5*. How can I see **12:00** in ODS and `getValue()`= **0.5**?

Comment: Hi W. Nel, when asking questions on SO it proves helpful to visually beef up your questions instead of writing everything without formatting. In addition, sharing an image with the error *might* be helpful to others.
Formatting your code (or formulas in your case) is as easy as `quoting them inline` or using an indented code block on its own.

Answer (score 0):

You can't see the date/time in ODS (or xlsx or xls, etc) using PHPExcel if you've used `setReadDataOnly(true)`....

The whole point of `setReadDataOnly(true)` is that it reads only the raw content of a cell, without any of the formatting information, such as that which identifies the cell as containing a date/time value.

Excel stores date/time values as a serialized timestamp, the number of days since a base start date (1st January 1900 or 1st January 1904, depending on the calendar setting), as a floating point value.
What identifies this as a date/time value is the number format mask, which specifies how that float should be displayed.

PHPExcel replicates this behaviour, and if you load the spreadsheet with `setReadDataOnly(false)`, then `getValue()` will return the serialized timestamp, while `getFormattedValue()` will apply the number format mask and return a formatted date/time string.
Conversely, if you load the file with `setReadDataOnly(true)`, there is no way that the code can identify this float as a date/time value, or know how it should be formatted other than as a float, because you elected not to load the formatting information that woul allow this identification too be made.

**TL/DR** Don't use `setReadDataOnly(true)` if you want PHPExcel to be able to identify date/time values as dates/times

Comment: Allow me to rephrase the question: I enter "12:00" in an Excel2007 cell, save the file as test.xlsx, I see "12:00" when I use Excel open test.xlsx, then I use PHP setReadDataOnly(true) and getValue(), the result is 0.5, it works for Excel2007.  I enter "12:00" in an Libre Calc cell, save the file as test.ods, I see "12:00" when I use LibreOffice open test.ods, then I use setReadDataOnly(true) and getValue(), the result is 25569.5, it doesn't work for ODS. If I format the cell as number in test.ods, I see "0.5" when I use LibreOffice, and getValue() is 0.5.

Comment: OK! You can report it as a bug in the [PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/issues) ODS Reader; it should be reading the value as 0.5, not as 25569.5. However, it won't be fixed for PHPExcel.... development of PHPExcel has been superseded by development of the next generation [PHPSpreadsheet](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/issues); so better to report the bug there.

Comment: Thanks @Mark. I have open an issue #1172: PHPExcel ODS Reader getValue() return a wrong number for Time.